# Extracting Salesforce data using Camel throws org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException

Tags: salesforce, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and working on a simple java program that can extract Salesforce custom object data using Apache Camel. While running the program it throws **org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException**. Objects QueryRecordsLine_Item__c and Line_Item__c implements Serializable interface. Kindly help me to fix this.

### Code snippet:

`from("direct:query")
   .to("salesforce:query?sObjectQuery=SELECT name, Unit_Price__c, Units_sold__c, Merchandise__c, Invoice_Statement__c from Line_Item__c&sObjectClass=" + QueryRecordsLine_Item__c.class.getName())

   .to("file:E:\\ajagan\\datafiles\\out");`

### Exception:

Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.dto.generated.QueryRecordsLine_Item__c to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {"done":true,"totalSize":280,"records":[.....]}
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:181)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)
    ... 31 more

Comment: Do you have the camel-salesforce jar file in your project build path?

Comment: Yes I have. Its been added as part of my maven script.

Answer (score 0):

You should add camel-jaxb to the classpath, so Camel can covert the salesforce DTO objects (they are JAXB annottated) to XML representation in a stream, that the file endpoint can use.

Comment: Link to error trace
https://backup.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6f668e6160757cb49a

Answer (score 0):

How about you try converting to a string first:

```
from("direct:query") 
.to(...)
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
.to(...)
```

Comment: Still the same error @ezzadeen. Earlier I tried using .convertBodyTo(InputStream.class)